# Can you listen for a value change in Firebase in AppDelgate class using Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, appdelegate

Is it possible to listen for a value change when the app is not opened at all, and then if there is a value changed in the tree/branch of the Firebase reference, then send the user a notification? That way I can say to the user their is a new message? Thoughts anyone? and would I put the following method

```
ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
print(snapshot.value)
})
```

in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in the AppDelagate Class?

Thanks.

Comment: You should look at background modes. There is a tutorial here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: you should look into firebase cloud functions and firebase cloud messaging. That way you can send notifications even when the app is terminated. You can set up a listener on the tree and have a function fire when the listener detects the change.

Comment: thanks guys, im trying to send a notification from a physical device not from the firebase console. My app can do a remote notification from firebase but I want to push a notification when someone pushes a button to update the Firebase tree. Hence when the tree is updated it just sends a notification to all user who has the app. I thought using the UserNotification library to push a notification to the user could be a strategy rater then using CloudKit etc.